# COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID changes from raw:[full file path] to msf:[number]

Tags: android

I opened a file using `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and "imported" it into the app's private storage for random access. With the uri I got, I tried to get the unique ID like so:

```
  cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
  {
    val nameIndex = 
    cursor.getColumnIndex(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID);
    docId = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
  }
```

My assumption is that the ID is some sort of a short unique string that never changes for the file. But, at least on the Android 12 emulator, it seems to be changing. Right after I drag-and-dropped the file into the emulator, I get something like `raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/file.name`. But if I do it a little bit later, I get something like `msf:62`. The document ID is not guaranteed to be invariant? Or is my logic incorrect?

All I want is some sort of invariant number or short string (preferably not containing any special characters) ID for a file that I selected from the system file chooser. Is there such a thing?

---

Here is the full code to reproduce the problem.

```
package com.example.sotest1

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.DocumentsContract
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener {
      val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
      intent.type = "application/epub+zip"
      startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)
    }
  }

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == 1234)
    {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
        val dataData = data!!.data!!
        val dataDataString = data!!.dataString!!;
        Log.d("stack", "data.data = $dataData");
        Log.d("stack", "data.data.path = ${dataData.path}");
        Log.d("stack", "data.dataString = $dataDataString");

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(dataData, null, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
          val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID);
          val docId = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
          Log.d("stack", "ID = $docId");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output 1: (opened the file in "Downloads").

```
2022-01-07 18:46:00.686 5879-5879/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ftest.epub
2022-01-07 18:46:00.687 5879-5879/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data.path = /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.epub
2022-01-07 18:46:00.687 5879-5879/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.dataString = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ftest.epub
2022-01-07 18:46:00.690 5879-5879/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: ID = raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.epub
```

Output 2: (opened the same file in "Downloads" after restarting the emulator. I saw it happening without restarting the emulator, but I do not know the exact condition and restarting seems to be a sure way to make it happen)

```
2022-01-07 18:52:39.054 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A86
2022-01-07 18:52:39.054 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data.path = /document/msf:86
2022-01-07 18:52:39.054 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.dataString = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A86
2022-01-07 18:52:39.096 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: ID = msf:86
```

Output3: (the same file, but on the left chose "sdk_gphone64_x86_64", clicked the "Download" directory and then chose the file)

```
2022-01-07 18:54:44.281 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data = content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ftest.epub
2022-01-07 18:54:44.282 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.data.path = /document/primary:Download/test.epub
2022-01-07 18:54:44.282 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: data.dataString = content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2Ftest.epub
2022-01-07 18:54:44.286 2022-2022/com.example.sotest1 D/stack: ID = primary:Download/test.epub
```

So, the same exact file in the exact same location, I get three different ID's: "raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.epub", "msf:86", and "primary:Download/test.epub".

Comment: I did not manually create the Uri; it was the one I got for `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` as I wrote above. It is `data?.data` within `override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)`, so there is not much to it.

Comment: @blackapps I have appended the full code to the question, so take a look at it.

Comment: Also add the value of data.path to both uries here. And compare. And comment. (And you should already have commented here that you saw that two times ID is contained in the content scheme).

Comment: @blackapps I see that it has `dataString` (which the document says "The same as getData(), but returns the URI as an encoded String."), but I do not see `path`. Do you mean `dataString`?  Anyway, I will test again with both `data` and `dataString` and update the question in a few minutes.

Comment: @blackapps Appended. It seems that there is not only the original problem but the ID becomes different if I locate same file from the root of the storage. So, in short, is there a way to get a unique invariant ID for the same file or not?

Comment: You are still on the wrong way athough i tried to show you what is going on. You still  did not comment on the fact that ID and path are contained in the content scheme you got. In both cases. A query() does not make any sense. You should realise why you got two different content schemes.

Comment: The title of your post should have been: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT delivers different uries for same file.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point that you get differet uries or different content schemes is because the user selected the same file in different ways.

The user has often three options to navigate to a file using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Using `Recent`. Using `Downloads`. Or browsing to external partition of phone and navigate to the folder the file is in.

The user will get two or three different uries/content schemes. They are from different providers/authorities as you can see.

You can get your first uri back if you just select the file in the same way you first did.

If you wanna reuse an uri then you should save and remember the whole content scheme. Does not matter which one.

(Only an ID makes no sense as you need the provider/authority too if you wanna use that ID later.)

But... take persistable uri permission in onActivityResult() first as otherwise your uri is invalid after restart of your app or even if you try to use it in another activity.